Unable to deploy change set to sandbox because of compilation error
I am encountering a bizarre issue with one of our sandbox orgs.
I modified a LWC in our testing org and I wanted to deploy the changes with a change set to a secondary sandbox org.
For some reason, when deploying the change set, it failed saying an apex class needs recompilation with the message that the method "isRunningTest" from the Test namespace wasn't recognized.
It was weird because the Apex class wasn't used by my LWC. I decided to compile all the apex classes in that org and virtually every class couldn't compile because the Test methods aren't recognized:

I've never encountered a similar issue beforem so I don't really know how to go on from here. I compiled my classes in our testing sandbox org and this doesn't happen.
Any help is appreciated

Looks like classic name shadowing. Do you have a class named just Test?

@DerekF no, we do not have a class named Test. We have the same codebase in both the sandbox orgs and this problem happens only in one of them

This is almost certainly name shadowing. Try using the workbench, under the REST Explorer, use /services/data/v58.0/tooling/sobjects/ApexClass/Name/Test, and see if you get a result.

It was indeed name shadowing.
An empty class named Test existed on the org. Once deleted, it resolved the issue.
